# Twitter Bad Authentication Data Error 215 with Tweepy

Tags: twitter

It seems everyone is panicking with new Twitter API v1.1 and I'm one of them...

So far, I've been able to use my twitter app with following authentication code

```
import tweepy

auth1 = tweepy.auth.OAuthHandler('My Consumer Key','My Consumer Secret')
auth1.set_access_token('Access Token','Access Token Secret')
api=tweepy.API(auth1)
url = "http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/show.json?id=" + someid
urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
```

I tried changing the 1 in url to 1.1 but it gives me bad authentication error...
I've created new access token but it also fails...
Is tweepy still usable under v1.1?
If so, what should I modify in my current code?
If not, what is the workaround?

If anyone could help me out, I would deeply appreciate it! :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Tweepy is retiring. There have been commits on Github since [the announcement](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tweepy/rWOKWGzdTVE) and discussion of handing over to others or merging with Twython, but that hasn't happened yet.

That said, I recommend taking a look at [Twython](https://github.com/ryanmcgrath/twython) as a replacement.